# On Restart Docker Swarm Managed Services are Not Coming Up

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have a swarm setup on a server and it ran out of space/hung. We did a restart and cleared some space and now none of the services are comming up.

I am really new to docker / swarm as it usually just runs and was setup by somebody else.

Here is the out put of `docker info`

```
Containers: 53
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 53
Images: 69
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-101188511-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 23.55 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 2.646 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 36.02 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.111 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-09-28)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: pending
 NodeID: 8vcqmfxgbmsisybt3l4cy6wd7
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: cfezpbtj3dyrcknx98g72creu
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: <ip>
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 15.51 GiB
Name: <name>
ID: SRS5:ZXV7:33PS:D4QS:C3QX:DJCD:DPRG:OAVJ:4QDG:BPSG:3K34:JBC4
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 docker.<name>.com
 127.0.0.0/8
```

As you can see the containers are all stopped. If i try to start a container again i get

```
docker start d601a004a6b7
Error response from daemon: network ingress not found
Error: failed to start containers: d601a004a6b7
```

So i get that the swarm is managing things but for some reason this didnt come up.
If i look at

```
docker service ls
ID            NAME                              REPLICAS  IMAGE                                                          COMMAND
0pydqzx86y1k  <name>-server-4-2-2               0/1       docker.<name>.com/<name>/<name>-server:4.2.2
0yusqmt4apag  <name>-4-2-5                      0/1       docker.<name>.com/<name>/<name>:4.2.5
```

I see the services but none seem started and there is no direct start command ?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service/

What command do i use to actually start these all up? And where should i be looking to diagnose what the problem is?

I thought it could be this:

```
 docker swarm init --advertise-addr <ip>
```

But this shows:

```
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

I also just noticed that

```
[root@usalvlhlpool1 /]# docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME       STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
8vcqmfxgbmsisybt3l4cy6wd7 *  <server>  Down    Active        Leader
```

And also this in /var/log/messages

```
Oct 17 16:43:01 usalvlhlpool1 dockerd: time="2017-10-17T16:43:01.232624716-04:00" level=error msg="controller resolution failed" module=worker task.id=03tr5rcal954b5bc4ouzeqb3k
Oct 17 16:43:01 usalvlhlpool1 dockerd: time="2017-10-17T16:43:01.232667687-04:00" level=error msg="failed to start taskManager" error="invalid volume mount source, must not be an absolute path: /root/hl-mediawiki/data/static" module=worker
```

I think his is the problem but where is swarm looking for this path? Where could i look

Comment: how are you running the services? through yml file or run command?

Comment: can you set restart_policy fro all your services. so that it starts as you restart your pc

Comment: To both of those questions this is RHEL i think that it was working before on restarts so something is preventing them to start this time.

I also noticed `docker node ls` is returning down (see above)